# The JPA query is returning a value, for a column, when the same query is returning null when executed in the pgadmin

Tags: java, plsql, spring-data-jpa, pgadmin

I have one Entity defined in my JAVA application,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="tm_table1")
@Getter
@Setter
@IdClass(CompositeKey.class)
public class ReadTableDao {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "seq1")
    private int seq1;
    
    @Id
    @Column(name = "seq2")
    private int seq2;
    
    @Column(name = "source_id")
    private int sourceId;
        
    @Column(name = "value_applied")
    private String valueApplied;
```

I have another class where I am reading these values using the JPA native query,

```
List<ReadTableDao> daoList = null;
if(someCondition){
daoList = repository.viewLotsAssmtCompleted(assessmentID, customerSeq);
}                       }
```

So, the query which is defined in the method "viewLotsAssmtCompleted()", returns three rows. Let's say row1, row2 and row3. My problem lies with the value of the fourth column which is "value_applied"

When I am executing the same query in the pgAdmin, the value for the specified column, I get is like this,

| Row | seq1 | seq2 | source_id | value_applied |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | NSLot1 | null |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | SerLot | Y |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | SerLot | null |

but when I am checking in java, I am getting:

| Row | seq1 | seq2 | source_id | value_applied |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | NSLot1 | null |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | SerLot | Y |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | SerLot | Y |

When I tried reading these values as

```
List<Object[]> list = repository.viewLotsAssmtCompleted(assessmentID, customerSeq);
```

I am getting the correct values as:

| Row | seq1 | seq2 | source_id | value_applied |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | NSLot1 | null |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | SerLot | Y |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | SerLot | null |

Why am I not able to read the correct values in the DAO object?

Why I am encountering such behavior?